# Progress feedback during Image Upload

Tags: feature-request, uploader

With the fancy new uploader, you can carry out the following steps:

1. Launch the uploader.
2. Click on the uploader.
3. Wait for your browser to open a file selection window. (On my overloaded, old machine, this regularly takes 4-7 seconds.)
4. Select a file to upload.
5. Wait for the preview to (upload? and) appear.
6. Approve the upload.
7. Wait for the final upload, while watching an "Upload..." animation to tell you something is happening.

At steps 3 and 5 (especially 5) there is a period of waiting with no feedback at all. Asking for a progress bar might be too much, but I would like to see some sort of feedback to acknowledge that I have done something, the server knows about it, and I need to be patient.

I dare guess that this is one of those areas where the web-developers have fast machines and super-fast network connectivity, and don't see how long it takes for distant users with machines that really could do with an upgrade.

(This was a problem with the old Image Uploader too, but with the fancy new one, it occurs to me to report it.)

Comment: This all depends on your OS and browser - when the OS is busy fetching files, the browser is most likely "frozen" anyway and can't show any progress. I fear your request is not technically possible.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Hence I said "Asking for a progress bar might be too much". However, before the call to the browser/OS, there could be a change in appearance of the page to make it clear that you HAVE selected something, and processing is happening. That seems technically possible.

Comment: I don't remember seeing any website ever having this... not that SE can't be unique, but just saying odds of this being done are pretty low.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I chose a site at random. Wordpress. When you click "Select files" the button border changes while the mouse is clicked, so you know it got the click (although I admit it changes back on button up, which is unfortunate.) Once the file is selected, you get a progress bar, until the file is uploaded and a preview is shown for selection.

Comment: The feedback I've got so far includes: "It can't be done.", "It shouldn't be done.", "It is never done that way.", "It should be done to a greater extent.", and "It is already being done to a lesser extent." I'm just waiting for:  "It is obvious should be done." and "It was always the intention to do it" and I will have the complete set.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, okay, I'm going to completely change my answer...

Naturally, when you open the file selection, it might take a while for the computer to get all the files and bring them back to you. Ouch. That can take seconds to minutes at times with no warning beforehand. Of course, no one can fix this dilemma but a progress bar should help with the waiting. It should be a similar one to Step 6:

[image]

And a good-old fashioned green progress bar for Step 3 and 4. It should be permanently enabled for every user. I hope this gets implemented!

Comment: No, step number 5 is about the time between clicking "Open" in the file selection dialog until the picture appears. (you talk about step 6).

Comment: It's time to edit! Again...

Comment: Nice, but your assumption of "early computer" which I guess means "old computer (?)" is also incorrect. Even brand new computer with super fast CPU can take long minutes to load those dialogs if something is bad with its hard disk e.g. bad sectors.

Comment: Just to be clear: My question is NOT a complaint that my machine runs too slowly. It is that when it does run too slowly, I have no feedback that anything is happening.

Comment: I suspect a progress bar is not technically feasible. This certainly doesn't deserve a separate option in your profile.